# "Student counsellor" or "study counsellor"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, difference

I need the title for someone whose work it is to give students advice about what courses to study in order to qualify for a certain job – I have found some support for both *study counsellor* and *student counsellor* on different universities' websites and the like, however, I get the impression that rather than being two names for the same thing, the latter – *student counsellor* – refers to someone lending emotional support/helping students who suffer from anxiety or depression or the like, rather than giving career advice. Am I right about this, or are *study counsellor* and *student counsellor* both used for someone giving career advice?

Comment: Are you using British or American English? Because in AmE, it's counselor. lso commonly known as a guidance counselor, provides students with academic, career, and college advice, as well as personal and social guidance. This can be accomplished through group counseling or individual counseling. Counselors also assist with annual academic planning for each student. This guide provides further information on what school counselors do, how to become one, [...] https://www.teachercertificationdegrees.com/careers/school-counselor/

Comment: @Lambie British English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "careers adviser" would be my preferred term.

Student counsellors give advice on student wellbeing (such as dealing with anxiety).  "Study counsellor" is not a term I recognise.  I see it used mostly on Scandinavian websites as a synonym for "student counsellor"

However "Careers adviser" is recognised job.  They give advise to students on how to attain a particular goal give training on (for example) how to write a letter of application, and advice on which courses to follow to qualify for a particular job.

Comment: What is a 'councellor'?

Comment: Bad spellificiation!!"

Comment: I thought it might be Swedish English.

Comment: Excellent answer as always – thanks!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Haha first I thought it was me who had misspelt... (I'm Swedish)